# Creating a 2d Dynamic array with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, 2d

So for an assignment I have to create a program that will create magic squares when the user inputs an odd number, I have most of the program done but for some reason when I try to populate the squares I get Unhandled exception at 0x00326315 in magic square.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

I'm using classes and have the declaration for square as int **square;

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include"MagicSquare.h"

using namespace std;

MagicSquare::MagicSquare(): size(0), maxNum(0), row(0), col(0), curNum(0) //Constructor initialize variables
{
}

MagicSquare::~MagicSquare()                             //Destructor 
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    delete[] square[i];
}
delete[] square;                                                                            //Delete the dynamically allocated memory
}
void MagicSquare::getSize() //Get the size of the magic square
{
    cout << "Please enter an odd number for the number of rows/columns: ";
    cin >> size;
    while (size % 2 == 0) //Check to see if the number entered is odd
    {
        cout << "The number you entered is not odd, please enter an odd number: ";
        cin >> size;
    }

    int **square = new (nothrow) int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        square[i] = new (nothrow) int[size];
    }
    maxNum = size * size;
    iCount = new (nothrow) int[size];
    jCount = new (nothrow) int[size];
}

void MagicSquare::populateSquare()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            square[i][j] = 0;     //This is where the error occurs
        }
    }
    curNum = 1;
    col = (size - 1) / 2;
    square[row][col] = curNum;
    curNum += 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++)
    {
        row = row - 1;
        col = col + 1;
        if (col >= size)
            col = 0;
        if (row < 0)
            row = size - 1;
        square[row][col] = curNum;
        curNum += 1;
    }
}
```

Header file

```
class MagicSquare
{
private:
int **square;
int size;
int maxNum;
int row;
int col;
int curNum;
int *iCount;
int *jCount;

public:
MagicSquare();
~MagicSquare();
void getSize();
void populateSquare();
void printSquare();
};
```

source file

```
#include"MagicSquare.h"
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() 
{
MagicSquare mySquare;

int choice = 1;
while (choice == 1)
{
    mySquare.getSize();
    mySquare.populateSquare();
    mySquare.printSquare();

    cout << "\n\nWould you like to create another magic square? 1 for yes, 0 for no: ";
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice != 1 || choice != 0)
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid input: \nWould you like to create another magic square? 1 for yes, 0 for no: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
}

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `new (nothrow)` without checking the returned value?  Also, give us something that compiles.

Comment: Teacher requires it, I don't normally use (nothrow)

Comment: Does your teacher REALLY say that you should not check the result from the `new` call, or simply that you should use `nothrow`? If that is the case, you should SERIOUSLY consider looking for another point of education, as it's a bit insane. (I was just about to write something similar to what tillaert wrote when it popped up)

Comment: @James Boyden Then you have to check whether the value is not equal to `NULL`. Because your new might fail. Check the value of size, it might be very large.

Comment: "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" this is a null pointer de-ref, use the debugger

Comment: She does require it, at the beginning of class she said that we should use it but that's all she said about it, most of what I know is browsing this, and other sites and reading a few C++ books.  I've been stepping through the debugger so I know where it crashes just not sure what it means.

Comment: @JBoyden - What is the purpose of `iCount` and `jCount`?  You allocate memory, but you failed to deallocate it, thus you have a memory leak.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Didn't correctly implement it, but its meant to count what is in each row and column to display the sums on the outside of the squares. Thanks for reminding me to deallocate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a local variable called `square` in your `getSize()` method here:

`int **square = new (nothrow) int*[size];`.

So you make space for the local variable but never for the class's field.

Change this line to

`square = new (nothrow) int*[size];`

Also seriously consider checking the results of the calls.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I'm looking up how to check the results now.

Answer (score 1):

Access violation reading location 0x00000000 is telling you, that you are trying to access a NULL-pointer.
A reason could be, that at least one call of `new` failed. you should check when allocating the array:

```
int **square = new (nothrow) int*[size];
if(square == NULL)
    //Handle error here
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    square[i] = new (nothrow) int[size];
    if(square == NULL)
        //Handle error here
}
```

But i guess thats not the reason. If I saw it right, you have two functions:

```
void MagicSquare::getSize() 
void MagicSquare::populateSquare()
```

But the `int **square` is created in getSize, so if you call populate square, this variable does not exist anymore.

if your class is:

```
class MagicSquare
{
private:
    int **square;
public:
    //Methods
}
```

in getSize you have to store the address in the classes member variable, not a local one you just created:

```
square = new (nothrow) int*[size]; //without int **
```